# Task Breaking: Microsoft Windows 2012R2, Task Scheduler, Excel 2013 VBScript

Tags: excel, vbscript, scheduled-tasks, office-automation, windows-server-2012-r2

I am trying to move some Excel automation Tasks (Task Scheduler) from an older (Win2003) server to a new Windows 2012 R2 server.

I can get it to work when I first create the task, but if I change anything it stops working and I can't figure out why, or how to stop it from changing. Any thoughts? (also see my second observation below)

### Here's What Happens

I create the initial task as shown below and it works fine, but if I change the user that the script runs as, It fails with the error:

```
Cannot run the macro 'Build'. The macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be disabled.
```

Changing the task to run as the original (working) user does not fix it. I get the same error when I re-run the task and have to delete/re-create it to get it to run again.

### File/Task Details

**D:\ApplicationDir\run.wsf** (simplified)

```
<job id="1">
<script language="VBScript">
  On Error Resume Next
  Dim excel
  Dim SourceFile 
  Set excel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
  SourceFile = "D:\ApplicationDir\File.xlsm"
  excel.Workbooks.Open SourceFile
  excel.Run "Build"
  excel.Workbooks.Close
  If Err <> 0 Then 
     ... write Err.Description to file ...
  End If
  Set excel = Nothing
</script>
</job>
```

**Task** (in Task Scheduler)

```
 - Runs as a user Account
 - Run whether user is logged on or not
 - Run with highest privileges
 - Configure For: Windows Server 2003, Windows XP or Windows 2000

Triggers:

 - Daily At 6:15 AM every day

Actions:

 - Start a Program:
 - Program: C:\Windows\System32\cscript.exe
 - Arguments: run.wsf
 - Start In: D:\Application_Dir\
```

### Another Observation

If I select any other "Configure for:" option, I lose the ability to select "Windows Server 2003, Windows XP or Windows 2000" altogether. The option just isn't there when I go back to edit the task properties. Any ideas why this is happening ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think Excel's macro security is done at the user level. You may want to login as the user whose credentials will be used for the scheduled task and then launch Excel and go into the Trust Center -> Macros section and set it to "Enable all macros". May not be the solution but it's at least one thing we can check off.

Comment: The task is running as the same user who created it and i have enabled all macros and added the D:\ApplicationDir to the Trusted Locations. When run from the command line (cscript run.wsf) it works 100% of the time regardless of which user on the system runs it (There's 3 of us)

When run from the Task Scheduler it only runs fine with the initial config. If I change anything it stops working, and even after I change the user back it still gives the error above.